# What do you call a row of keys (music)?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

What do you call a single row of keys on a keyboard if it has more than one (for example on an organ)? Is "claviature" the right word for it (example: "The keyboard of the organ has 4 claviatures.")?

Comment: Seeing how you are trying to translate *Klaviatur*, you should start by looking it up in a bilingual dictionary of your choice. Or just check out [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaviatur), which not only has the English translation, but actually points out that the musical term in German is *Manual* as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An organ has one or more ***manuals*** (and, usually, a *pedalboard* which the organist plays with his feet).

> **manual** *noun*
>
> **3** an organ keyboard played with the hands not the feet.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manual?q=manual)

The collection of manuals, together with the stops, is called the *console*. However, one would normally say "the organ has four manuals" rather than "the organ console has four manuals", because the manuals are always in the console.

Comment: What a wonderfully misleading phrase for someone who knows nothing about musical instruments. If I saw the sentence, “The organ has four manuals” (out of context, obviously), I’m sure I would be left wondering why anyone could possibly need more than just one user guide for a heart or a liver …

Comment: @Janus Every phrase ever is misleading for someone who knows nothing about the subject at hand. Even more so if it's out of context.

Comment: Yes: I have learnt something in 35 years of playing organs!

Comment: What about synthesizers that have more than one row of keys?

Comment: What about them? I'd call those manuals, too; but then I'm an organist. Others might call them *upper* and *lower keyboards,* perhaps. The question was about organs, which, as Janus has noted, have a specialised vocabulary.

Comment: @Peter I've never seen that on synths, only on electronic organs.

Comment: @Andalur: A few synthesizers have them. For example, [here](http://artsites.ucsc.edu/ems/music/equipment/synthesizers/analog/moog/moog.html).

Comment: @PeterShor OK, it seems they simple stacked 2 keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

An organ *console* has one or more *keyboards* (if you mean to be played with the hands or feet) or one or more *manuals* (if you are referring only to keyboards played by the hands).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_console